# Oracle Multiple insert with different values

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How to update multiple rows in the oracle database with different record set.

Comment: May be you need to create a block.

Comment: please show some code - what is the goal ? what have you tried ? what doesn't work ?

Comment: Please make up your mind - do you want to INSERT, UPDATE or both?

Answer (score 2):

It's not pretty, but you can do this with [MERGE INTO](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm), using a UNION of SELECT ... FROM DUAL as the merge source.

Given:

```
create table writer (
    id integer primary key,
    name varchar2(255) not null
)
```

You can do:

```
merge into writer dst
using (
    select 1 as id, 'Edward Luttwak' as name from dual
    union
    select 2 as id, 'Iain Sinclair' as name from dual
) src
on (dst.id = src.id)
when matched then update set dst.name = src.name
when not matched then insert (dst.id, dst.name) values (src.id, src.name);
```

For each row you want to update, add a term to the union in the subquery. If you know that the rows are definitely updates, and never inserts, you can drop the whole `when matched` clause.